# Is there a way to check if a string is alphanumeric in erlang

Tags: string, erlang, alphanumeric

I am collecting tweets from twitter using erlang and I am trying to save only the hashtags to a database. However when I'm converting the bitstrings to list-strings all the non-latin-letter tweets converts to strange symbols. 
Is there any way to check if a string is only containing alphanumeric characters in erlang?

Comment: Wouln't it be better to solve the main Problem? To convert utf8-encoded bitstrings correctly, do not use `binary_to_list` but the `unicode`-module.

Comment: Sorry, I suck at erlang. What do you mean? Can I convert only the latin letter tweets to list with the unicode module?

Comment: No, that means if you want to deal with a utf8-encoded bitstring (with all special symbols beeing represented correctly), use the proper module.

Comment: Sorry, I tried using the unicode:characters_to_list/2 and it converts everything correctly. However I don't think I will need to save other than alphanumeric hashtags anyways. I really appreciate the help though.

Comment: No need to excuse yourself, I have been in your situation not so long ago ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way is to use regular expressions.

```
StringAlphanum = "1234abcZXYM".
StringNotAlphanum = "1ZXYMÄ#kMp&?".

re:run(StringAlphanum, "^[0-9A-Za-z]+$").
>> {match,[{0,11}]}

re:run(StringNotAlphanum, "^[0-9A-Za-z]+$").
>> nomatch
```

You can easily make a function out of it...

```
isAlphaNum(String) -> 
    case re:run(String, "^[0-9A-Za-z]+$") of
        {match, _} -> true;
        nomatch    -> false
    end.
```

But, in my opinion, the better way would be to solve the underlying Problem, the correct interpretation of unicode binary strings.

If you want to represent unicode-characters correctly, do not use `binary_to_list`. Use the [unicode-module](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/unicode.html) instead. Unicode-binary strings can not be interpreted *naiveley* as binary, the UTF-8 character encoding for example has some special constraints that prevent this. For example: the most significant bit in the first character determines, if it is a multi-byte character.

I took the following example from [this site](http://blog.teemu.im/2011/10/31/string-encodings-in-erlang/), lets define a UTF8-String:

```
Utf8String = <<195, 164, 105, 116, 105>>.
```

Interpreted *naiveley* as binary it yields:

```
binary_to_list(Utf8String).
"Ã¤iti"
```

Interpreted with unicode-support:

```
unicode:characters_to_list(Utf8String, utf8).
"äiti"
```

Comment: Yes i tried converting with unicode to list and it works. Thank you. However I think I will only need alphanumeric tweets anyways

Answer (score 3):

for latin chars you can use this function:

```
is_alpha([Char | Rest]) when Char >= $a, Char =< $z ->
    is_alpha(Rest);
is_alpha([Char | Rest]) when Char >= $A, Char =< $Z ->
    is_alpha(Rest);
is_alpha([Char | Rest]) when Char >= $0, Char =< $9 ->
    is_alpha(Rest);
is_alpha([]) ->
    true;
is_alpha(_) ->
    false.
```

for other coding, you can add their rang of code and add them.

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what i needed!

Answer (score 3):

There are three io_lib functions specifically for this:

- `io_lib:printable_list/1`
- `io_lib:printable_latin1_list/1`
- `io_lib:printable_unicode_list/1`

Here is [an example of one in use](https://github.com/zxq9/zxWidgets/blob/master/src/zxw.erl#L108-L116):

```
-spec show_message(ExParent, Message) -> ok
    when WxParent :: wx:wx_object(),
         Message  :: unicode:chardata() | term().

show_message(WxParent, Message) ->
    Format =
        case io_lib:printable_unicode_list(Message) of
            true  -> "~ts";
            false -> "~tp"
        end,
    Modal = wxMessageDialog:new(WxParent, io_lib:format(Format, [Message])),
    _ = wxMessageDialog:showModal(Modal),
    ok = wxMessageDialog:destroy(Modal).
```

Check out the io_lib docs: http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/io_lib.html#printable_list-1

**Addendum**

Because this subject isn't always easy to research in Erlang a related, but slightly broader Q/A might be of interest:

[How to check whether input is a string in Erlang?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46335355/how-to-check-input-is-string-in-erlang/46337134#46337134)